# What is the difference between the dotnet and dnx command line tools?

Tags: asp.net, .net, mono, dnx

I'm getting confused by all the cross platform .NET tools out there.  What is the difference between the [`dotnet`](http://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/) tool and the [`dnx`](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-mac.html) tool, and what is the relationship between them?  What is the difference between .NET Core and Mono?

Are Mono and .NET Core two separate frameworks/implementations of .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dnx is going away and is being replaced with dotnet.

.Net Core is a cross platform runtime that can cross platform. It is much smaller and leaner than .NET Framework and can be published withe the app making the app self contained. You can run different versions of .NET Core side by side (there is no GAC)

Mono is more like a .NET Framework counterpart for non-Windows.